# li:last-child element height 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stretch the height of the last list item to 100% to match the dynamic height of the div floated right.

```
ul.menu li:last-child {height:100%}
```

example of where i've got..

http://jsfiddle.net/kvtV8/1/

[image]

any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for can be done but IMHO there is no pretty solution in current CSS. Here is one possibility that works (sort of).

For the list to be aware of the size of the floated element next to it, both need to be contained in the same element (container):

```
<div id="container">
  <ul class="menu">
    …
    <li>…</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="floated">…</div>
</div>
```

For that container to be aware of the size of the floated element in it, it needs to float as well:

```
#container {
  float: left;
}
```

Because the next sibling of the container element would then float next to it (unless it had its `clear` property set to `left` or `both`), you might need to clear after it:

```
<div id="container">
  …
</div>
<div style="clear: both; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0"><!-- for MSHTML --></div>

<!-- next sibling here -->
```

And for the list item element to have its lower boundary aligned with the lower boundary of the floated element, it needs to be positioned `absolute` –

```
ul.menu li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

– and the container needs to be positioned `relative` so that the `li` element's `bottom: 0` means zero distance from the bottom of the floated element (unless it is not as high as the list):

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

However, if you position the last list item like that, you are losing the dynamically computed coordinates for its left and upper boundary.

I can see only one way and only a possibility to fix that final problem if you know how much space the list items above the last one take. That will be harder to maintain, but if you want to go for it, here you are:

```
ul.menu li:last {
  position: absolute;

  /* in your case */
  left: 0;

  /*
   * Assumption: 3 items above, each has a computed height of 1em, no margins
   * in-between.  (Obviously, until CSS3 Computed Values becomes widely adopted,
   * you would need to use the same unit of length here as you use for the
   * heights of the list items above and possible margins between them.)
   */
  top: 3em; 

  bottom: 0;
}
```

Obviously, the `ul` element *must not* be positioned then, or your `li` coordinates will be off.

In summary, the CSS –

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

/* AIUI from your original code */
#container #floated {
  float: right;
}

#container ul.menu li:last-child {
  position: absolute;

  /* see above */
  left: 0;
  top: 3em;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

– and the markup:

```
<div id="container">
  <ul class="menu">
    …
    <li>…</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="floated">…</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both; width: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0"><!-- for MSHTML --></div>

<!-- next sibling here -->
```

WFM in Chromium 22. But AISB, it is not pretty. You should reconsider why you need the last list item to be stretched like this. Maybe what you *really* want to do is to stretch the list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put html and body height to 100%

Try using this line:

```
html, body, section {width:100%; height:100%;}
```

Comment: This works because the browser now has a set height for the body, which in turn grants the section a set height.  Since `ul.menu` is already height:100%, it can now use these already calculated values.   css height in percentages only takes effect if some parent has a specified height value.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question, which is regarding the size of a floated element.

Comment: so what is the issue in this answer, question is "trying to stretch the height of the last list item to 100%" and this is helping achieving that so i think this has to be the right answer.

Comment: No, that is *not* the question. Read it again.

Comment: You are missing the point. Where is the *floated DIV element next to the list* considered in your answer?